# Algorithm for finding triangles within a region

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry

I am working on small project that requires me to quickly find which triangles within a set of triangles is either partially or entirely contained within a given rectangular region.  I am interested in optimizing for fast searches - I am not memory limited.

This is not an area I am too familiar with, so all I've been able to do thus far is to poke around on Google for standard algorithms for dealing with this problem.  The closest I've gotten to so far is to use two interval trees.  This is a bit clumsy, since I have to perform a test for interval overlap between the edges of each triangle and the edges of the rectangular region in both directions x and y.

Can someone point me to any resource where the 'correct' way of dealing with this problem is?

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention that the rectangular regions I am currently using are parallel to the coordinate axes x and y.  For the time being, I am happy with any solution that exploits this constraint.  Generally, though, a solution with completely arbitrary rectangles would be great to know about.

Comment: Are the rectangular regions' sides parallel to the coordinate axes (there's a word for that, but I forgot it)? If so, you could use the rectangles enclosing your triangles to build 2-dimensional interval trees (or segment trees or range trees or whatever those structures are called) and see whether those solve your issues efficiently enough.

Comment: Right.  That is the approach I took.  It was still pretty slow, but I am not confident the interval tree implementation I pulled was well optimized.

Comment: This is a slightly specialized version of collision detection, which is good for a search term.  See for example http://q3k.org/gentoomen/Game%20Development/Programming/Real-Time%20Collision%20Detection.pdf

Comment: A general solution for checking the intersection of any two convex shapes is to write it as a linear program and checking for feasibility. It is not clear whether it is faster than a geometric approach, though

Comment: The advantage of this method is it generality (any two convex shapes) and also it does not need the rectangle to be horizontal or vertical...

Comment: How many triangles? How often is the list updated? What's the size of the whole 2D space?

Comment: Is preprocessing allowed ? I mean, for a given triangle set, do you need to solve the problem for numerous different rectangular windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an AABBTree (AABB stands for Axis Aligned Bounding Box tree), the
idea is to enclose each triangle in its axis aligned bounding box, then build a tree that has the initial triangles as leafs, and where upper nodes have a bounding box that is the union of the bounding boxes of its children. Then when searching which triangles have a non-empty intersection with "something", you check whether the "something" has an intersection with the bounding box of a node, and go down the tree to test its children when it's the case (recursive function).

You can find efficient implementations of AABBTrees in:

- CGAL: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/
- the GEOGRAM library that I am writing: http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/classGEO_1_1MeshFacetsAABB.html
- OpCode: http://www.codercorner.com/Opcode.htm

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rectangle is axis aligned, I'd do this:

1. Compare the bounding box of a triangle to the region. If it is inside, the triangle is inside. If there is no overlap at all, it's not. Use an interval tree for each dimension for this step if you need to check the same set of triangles with different regions.
2. We have checked the two simple cases in step one, so we know the region and bounding box overlap. Check if any of the points of the triangle is inside the rectangle. If so, the triangle is inside.
3. Check the four sides of the rectangle with the three sides of the triangle for line segment intersections

Answer (score 1):

If no preprocessing of the set of triangles is allowed, there is nothing better you can do than comparing exhaustively every triangle to the window.

To solve the triangle/rectangle overlap problem easily (or just to reason about it), you can form the Minkowski sum of the two polygons, to turn the problem in a "point-in-convex-polygon" instance.

[image]

Of course, an initial axis-aligned bounding box test is welcome.

If your window is a rotated rectangle, you can "unrotate" the whole scene to make the window axis-aligned and revert to the first problem.